# Is there a way to get an Image from a path on the server and pass it into an IFormFile variable or property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I need to get an image(IFormFile) which is stored on the server in a folder to a controller making the request. I have a model which contains a **Logo** as an **IFormFile** like below:

```
public IFormFile Logo { get; set; }
```

**Logo** is in a Model called Label and there are multiple fields in there. My goal is to send the whole model and then append the **IFormFile** to the **label** object and specifically to the Logo property and send it altogether to the other end. Is there a way i can achieve this?

```
 Stream outStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("wwwroot//labels//IMG_20190322_180828.jpg"));
var label = _database.Labels.Where(d => d.Id == labelId).FirstOrDefault();
            label.Logo = (IFormFile)outStream;
            return Ok(label);
```

I know i cannot convert a stream to an IFormFile but i wrote it here for demo. I can get the file in a stream as above but how do i append it to the Logo or is there a better way i can send an image?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `IFormFIle` is... (it's strictly for client-to-server `multipart/form-data` binary uploads). I think what you really want is a multipart **response** (assuming you're not targeting web-browsers making document requests), or serve the image separately, passing only a URI to it in your response somehow.

Comment: So i can pass a link directly to my resource and display it on the other end?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Your `wwwroot` folder in your project is already publicly served anyway, so you don't need to do anything special server-side.

Comment: Alright thank you. Let me try this

Comment: Note that you should use `IPhysicalFileProvider` to retrieve the file contents if the file name is influenced by the client in any way. Otherway a malicious client may be able to retrieve arbitrary files from your application or machine, such as application code/configuration or operating system contents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0 https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal